# java unicode encoded file reading problem in jdk 1.3

Tags: java

I am using jdk1.3 for blackberry platform. Now I am facing a problem when I trying to read an Unicode encoded xml file.

My code :

```
java.io.BufferedReader br = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(new java.io.FileInputStream(path),"UTF16"));
br.readLine();
```

Error:

```
sun.io.MalformedInputException: Missing byte-order mark
    at sun.io.ByteToCharUnicode.convert(ByteToCharUnicode.java:123)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.convertInto(InputStreamReader.java:137)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.fill(InputStreamReader.java:186)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:249)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:139)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:299)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:362)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `XML` file is missing a [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

In JDK 1.3, the byte order mark [is mandatory](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/lang/package-summary.html#charenc) if you use `UTF-16`. Try the `UTF16-LE` or `-BE` if you know in advance what the endianness is.

(The BOM is not mandatory in 1.4.2 and above.)

Of course, if your file is not `UTF-16` at all, use the correct encoding. See the above link to character encodings. The actual encodings supported, apart from a small set of core encodings, are implementation defined so you'll need to check the docs for your particular JDK.

The encoding the files are in is supposed to be in the `<xml>` header of your files, something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="THIS IS THE ENCODING YOU NEED TO USE"?>
```

If the file is in a single character encoding, or `UTF-8` (without a BOM), You can try reading the first line with plain `US-ASCII`, it shouldn't contain any data outside that range. Parse the encoding field, then re-open the file with the deduced encoding.

This will only work if the actual encoding is supported by your platform obviously.

BTW: JDK 1.3 is ancient. Are you sure that's your version? (Doesn't change anything to the problem anyway except for the BOM part)

Comment: LE/BE nothing is working. Showing error sun.io.MalformedInputException

Comment: are you certain the files are in UTF-16 to begin with? post the first lines (with the `<xml>` header), and the first few lines of hexdump output of on file.

Comment: No I am not sure. Some lines from the file : "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1256"?>
<NewsML>
 <!--Processed by SDDCO-->
"

Comment: But How to read that first line. It is showing the error without reading anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
java.io.BufferedReader br = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(new java.io.FileInputStream(path),"Windows-1256"));
br.readLine();
```